# How to use Magento 2 with an openlitespeed (free) web server?

Tags: .htaccess, magento2, magento-2.0, litespeed, magento-2.3

I'm trying to setup Magento 2.3.0 server with OpenLiteServer and keep on bumping weird Rewrite rule errors:

[image: LiteSpeed errors]

Here's the [full list](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/SudoPlz/c794a69b30a7831420e0734f9d0eb92a/raw/42ba704a46955ee2231253d31ed0a6db75f82d98/open%2520lite%2520speed%2520errors) of errors.

The [website](https://www.tyanabelle.com) is working, but CSS and JS cannot be loaded so there are lot's of 404s

[image: tyanabelle.com]

I'm thinking that I may be doing something wrong, or that OpenLiteSpeed does not support all of those commands inside the `.htaccess` files.

The magento 2 installation is just a basic magento 2.3.0 composer installation without anything added to it, and thus is set to **default** mode.

The file permissions are looking good too, but note that files are missing from the `pub/static/frontend/luma/en_US/` directory:

[image: permissions]

Any hints?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the website is under `/magento2` you'll need to insert the rewrites on the virtual host, at the rewrites section, enable the rewrite module as well.

```
  RewriteRule ^/magento2/pub/static/version.+?/(.+)$ /magento2/pub/static/$1 [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule /magento2/pub/static/.* /magento2/pub/static.php?resource=$0 [L]
  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
  RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule .* /magento2/index.php [L]
```